# Any good example about Autocomplete with Zend Framework? (JQuery and ZendX)

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, autocomplete, zendx

I have a problem, I don't find good examples of "autocomplete" with zend framework (using jQuery with zendx). I need one that works to understand how to develop it.

Someone has done it?

Thank you very much in advance

PS: I know how to do it without ZendX, I mean, doing the form myself (and using jquery as usual with a autocomplete.php file using the parameter typed in the input field), but I would like to use the zend framework properly, so I would like to know if someone has made it

Comment: Come on guys!
Anybody have a good example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just watched this: http://www.zendcasts.com/autocomplete-control-with-zendx_jquery/2010/07/
Really great. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Autocomplete functionality (which was just reintroduced w/ jQuery UI 1.8) is [back in 1.10](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9007). [Here is the new documentation for it](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zendx.jquery.form.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it would be the job of Zend to handle a special front-end UI widget like that. I keep it simple, but adding a CSS class to the input field in the view, and providing a controller action that returns results in JSON. My front-end javascript attaches the autocomplete behavior to any input forms with the CSS class on it.

You can even add an HTML5 data- attribute ([blog post](http://fullware.net/2010/03/11/custom-attributes-in-the-dom/)) with the URL of the action to hit, so your handler can be agnostic.

Comment: I know this.
In fact, I'm doing it without the ZendX, but I've seen something about this and I hope I can do it in this way!

Thanks ;-)